# Do metro apps in windows 8 lose their internet connection when I switch to the desktop or any other app?

Tags: windows-8-preview, modern-ui

I am using Windows 8 Release preview.

One thing that seems irritating to me is that when I browse using metro IE after entering URL I switch to desktop for using other apps, so that the page loads in the mean time. But problem is, the page does not load in the mean time.

When I go back to the browser, the page starts loading again. This is same for some other metro apps like messenger. Is this the default behavior or some problem with my connection? Better to state, I have a pretty slow internet connection.

Answer (score 4):

Its not the internet connection - they go into a [sort of suspended state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx#app_suspend) when you switch out from them, and is by design, allegedly to save resources. Its the default behaviour, however.